# Facebook api for different environments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook

I've an application integrated with Facebook Connect. My application is deployed on different environments (production, staging, development) with different domains.

Is there a way to set up Facebook app, so that it work with all my environments? Or should I create separate facebook apps for each env?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're relying on things such as callback URLs, then no. Those are tied to one specific URL. Separate Facebook apps sounds like the way to go. Just have the app info be in your web configuration.